# Spotfire: Modify both Content and Orientation of Bar Chart Labels

Tags: formatting, label, spotfire

I've had a request to modify the label content and orientation in a Spotfire bar horizontal chart.  I know I can change the orientation of the bar value, but not the content, as well as change the content but not the orientation of label on the line I've added.  However, I need to be able to change both the value and the orientation so that it looks something like the picture below.

Is this possible - either via the program or via scripting of some sort?

Thanks for any help,

Crystal

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible... but you could use an annotation in 7.5 versions onward.